# C# WPF compare List<T> to Datagrid.ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid, itemssource

I bound my `private List<MaintenanceWindow> tempMaintenanceWindows` to a Datagrid and enabled the user to edit the items in the Datagrid as well as to add new items. This works fine.

Now I thought about how to rollback the changes the user made if the window is closed without pressing the save button first. Basically, I want to compare the Datagrid.ItemsSource to the temporary List I populated like this:

```
foreach (MaintenanceWindow mainWin in maintenanceWindowList)
                tempMaintenanceWindows.Add(new MaintenanceWindow {from = mainWin.from, to = mainWin.to, abbreviation = mainWin.abbreviation, description = mainWin.description, hosts = mainWin.hosts });
```

I compare the two like so:

```
if (!tempMaintenanceWindows.SequenceEqual((List<MaintenanceWindow>)mainWinList.ItemsSource))
```

but the result of the SequenceEqual always seems to be false, although when debugging the code, they seem to be the exact same thing.

Hope someone can help. Thanks.

---

Quentin Roger provided an approach solution which works but I want to post my code which is probably not the neatest way to do it but it fits to my case of application.

**So this is how I overrode the Equals method of my MaintenanceWindow object:**

```
public override bool Equals (object obj)
        {
            MaintenanceWindow item = obj as MaintenanceWindow;

            if (!item.from.Equals(this.from))
                return false;
            if (!item.to.Equals(this.to))
                return false;
            if (!item.description.Equals(this.description))
                return false;
            if (!item.abbreviation.Equals(this.abbreviation))
                return false;
            if (item.hosts != null)
            {
                if (!item.hosts.Equals(this.hosts))
                    return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.hosts != null)
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: SequenceEqual use the default comparer, did you override equals for the MaintenanceWindow ?

Comment: The default comparer, does that mean it compares like tempElement1.Equals(gridElement1) and so on? No, I did not override it. So in the override method do I have to compare every single field of my MaintenanceWindow class?

Comment: Exactly you have to compare every significant fields.

Comment: Ok, so now I did override the Equals method and of course it works, thank you for the clarification! If you post a short answer I will mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I already post an answer with a possible implementation of the equals function ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare your MaintenanceWindow like this :

As I said in my comment you have to compare every significant fields.In the following implementation I chose description, so if two `MaintenanceWindow` got the same `description` they ll be considered equals and the SequenceEquals ll work as expected.

```
 internal class MaintenanceWindow
 {
    public object @from { get; set; }
    public object to { get; set; }
    public object abbreviation { get; set; }

    private readonly string _description;
    public string Description => _description;

    public MaintenanceWindow(string description)
    {
        _description = description;
    }

    public string hosts { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals((MaintenanceWindow)obj);
    }

    protected bool Equals(MaintenanceWindow other)
    {
        return string.Equals(_description, other._description);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _description?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default SequenceEqual will compare each item calling the equal function, do you override the equal? Otherwise it compares the memory adress for a class.

Also I encourage you to use [FSharpList](https://lookingsharp.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/converting-an-ilist-to-an-fsharplist/) when you are looking for immutable list comparison.

> "So in the override method do I have to compare every single field of
>   my MaintenanceWindow class"

You have to compare every meaningful fields, yes.